# Why are we allowed to disregard the negative square root while solving this limit?

Tags: calculus

I was taking a limit of a function as such:

$\lim_{x\to+\infty} \frac{\sqrt{x^2+2}}{3x-6}$

$\rightarrow \lim_{x\to+\infty} \frac{\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{x^2} + \frac{2}{x^2}}}  {\frac{3x}{|x|}-\frac{6}{|x|}}$

$\rightarrow \lim_{x\to+\infty} \frac{\sqrt{1 + \frac{2}{x^2}}}  {\frac{3x}{x}-\frac{6}{x}}$

$\rightarrow \lim_{x\to+\infty} \frac{\sqrt{1 + \frac{2}{x^2}}}  {3-\frac{6}{x}}$

$\rightarrow \frac{\sqrt{1+0}}{3-0}$

$=\frac{\sqrt1}{3}$

$=\frac{1}{3}$

Similarly, we could take the limit as $x$ approaches $-\infty$ as such:

$\vdots$

$\rightarrow \lim_{x\to-\infty} \frac{\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{x^2} + \frac{2}{x^2}}}  {\frac{3x}{|x|}-\frac{6}{|x|}}$

$\rightarrow \lim_{x\to-\infty} \frac{\sqrt{1 + \frac{2}{x^2}}}  {\frac{3x}{-x}-\frac{6}{-x}}$

$\rightarrow \lim_{x\to-\infty} \frac{\sqrt{1 + \frac{2}{x^2}}}  {-3+\frac{6}{x}}$

$\rightarrow \frac{\sqrt{1+0}}{-3+0}$

$=\frac{\sqrt1}{-3}$

$=-\frac{1}{3}$

However, where I'm confused is near the end of the problem. At $\frac{\sqrt{1}}{3}$ and $\frac{\sqrt{1}}{-3}$, the solution specifies that we take the positive square root of $1$ only, thus $\sqrt{1}=1$. Why can't we take the negative root of $\sqrt{1}$ here and yield $-1$? I understand that this would give us two different limits, but how is it that the positive root is the right choice? Thank you!

Comment: The symbol $\sqrt{\phantom{0}}$ **means** "positive square root." It's that simple.

Comment: Okay. So, the principal square root. I thought the symbol was more ambiguous and implied $\pm \sqrt$. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: When we need to consider both roots we can simply write $\pm,$ as in the usual formula for solving a quadratic equation. I'm sure this question has come up more than once on this site.

Comment: Got it. I thought there was some ambiguity associated with the operator, and didn't recognize that in the context of this problem.

Answer (score 2):

$\sqrt{x}$ takes only positive values by definition.